# Bootstrap nestable.js

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to implement a search tool for a nestable list in bootstrap with this code:

```
$('#btn-ricerca').on("click",function(){
    id= $('#ricerca').val();
    $('.dd').nestable("expandItem("+$('#'+id)+")");
});
```

then i want to set focus on the item selected.

Comment: Please describe in greater detail what it is that you're trying to achieve. I've dealt with nestable.js frequently and I'm happy to try and help.

Comment: I was trying to expand only the items that match with the search field . In the end i ve found a solution different from the this one, hidding the rows that dont match with the search. Thx anyway ;)